# cant install visual studio 2013 professional core features fatal error

Tags: visual-studio, fatal-error

i want to install visual studio 2013 professional very much but i cant it's throwing error every time i try to install (visual studio core features fatal error during installation) it here's log - http://pastebin.com/NP77aNFN

i want to learn programming in visual studio and open whole new world to me but it's keep doing that. i have 2010 and 2008 versions but i want to try new one.

i tried installing ultimate version too but it was throwing same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the setup you are trying to install could be corrupt.
So you should restart the system and install freshly downloaded setup of visual studio.

Comment: i downloaded it four times may it be other problem?